# What would prevent Firefox from animating a css transform?

Tags: css, sass

http://jsfiddle.net/jimcamut/xyudhgLx/

When the window is wider than 960px, see how the main menu (white links on gray background) behave in Firefox vs Chrome when you scroll down. Chrome runs the CSS animation transition while Firefox doesn't, even though Firefox is reading the CSS. In firefox the menu jumps to its transform: translate(0,0) and ignores the transition.

I can't figure this one out and haven't found any explanations for this bug.

Below is the SCSS I'm using for the elements in question.

```
$prefixes: "-webkit-", "-moz-", "-ms-","-o-", "";
@mixin all($action, $stuff...) {
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
        #{$prefix}#{$action}:$stuff;
    }
}


    // PRE Sticky Phase
    .navWrapper {
        .e-icon, .dots-icon, .more-icon {
            @include all(transition, 0.4s ease);
            @include all(transform, translateY(-100%));
        }
        .e-icon {margin-right: 30px; @include all(transition-delay, 0s);}
        .more-icon {display: none;}
       ul#nav {
            @include all(transition, 0.6s ease);
            @include all(transform, translate(-83px,0));
            @include all(transition-delay, 0.2s);
        }
    }


    // Sticky Phase
    .navWrapper.stick {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        .e-icon, .dots-icon, .more-icon {
            @include all(transform, translateY(0));
        }
        .e-icon, .dots-icon {@include all(transition-delay, 0.4s);}
        ul#nav {
            @include all(transform, translate(0,0));
            @include all(transition-delay, 0s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you have a pure CSS problem, its better to just provide the compiled CSS and *only* provide the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because **you're changing the parent's position** ([bug #821976](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=821976)).

Here's a minimal example to understand the problem:
(**run under both Chrome and Firefox to see the issue**)

```css
.container {
    margin: 80px;
    float: left;
}
.container.positioned {
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: tomato;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
html:hover .container {
    position: relative;
}
html:hover .container .content {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container positioned">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

The usual solution provided is to separate the parent's positioning change from the child's transition (delaying the second one). Here's how to start with your code:

**1-** Use two classes instead of `.navWrapper.stick` : `.stick` (for children transition), and `.stick-self` (for self positioning):

```
// Sticky Phase
.navWrapper.stick-self {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.navWrapper.stick {
    .e-icon, .dots-icon, .more-icon {
        @include all(transform, translateY(0));
    }
    .e-icon, .dots-icon {@include all(transition-delay, 0.4s);}
    ul#nav {
        @include all(transform, translate(0,0));
        @include all(transition-delay, 0s);
    }
}
```

**2-** Add/remove `.stick-self` first, and delay `.stick`'s add/removal:

```
var swapDivs = function (bool) {
    if (bool) {
        $(".navWrapper").addClass("stick-self");
        setTimeout(function() {
           $(".navWrapper").addClass("stick");
           $(".co-links").addClass("sub").insertAfter(".dummy-bg");
        }, 50);            
    } else {
        $(".navWrapper").removeClass("stick-self");
        setTimeout(function() {
           $(".navWrapper").removeClass("stick");
           $(".co-links").removeClass("sub").insertAfter("#top-menu .container .ref");
        }, 50);
    }
};
```

Comment: Awesome bug find, awesome explanation and awesome solution! Works like a charm now. Thanks so much for taking the time to tackle this - I was at wit's end.